# Classification of algebra morphism from $M_n(K)$ to $L(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, and $V$ a $K$-vector space with finite dimension and 
let $f$ be a morphism of algebras between $M_n(K)$ and $L(V)$ (where $L(V)$ means the space of endomorphism of $V$).

Show that $n$ divides $\dim V$ and show that there exist a basis $\beta$ such that for every matrix $A$ of $M_n(K)$:
$$\operatorname{Mat}_{\beta}(f(A))= \operatorname{Diag}(A,.....,A). $$

My attempt is to prove the second result and then easily deduce the first one from the second.

Comment: so the whole problem is about finding such a basis

Comment: Is $Mat_\beta$ the name of the morphism?

Comment: $Mat_{\beta}(f(A))$ means the matrice of the linear map f(A) is the basis $\beta$

Comment: @Seginus: Matrix, not matrice.

Comment: thanks @anormaly , any idea